# ASP.NET Core 8 Identity authorization-authentication with roles policy

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-8

In an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, I have this configuration related to authorization and authentication:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

This version allows me connect using cookies or bearer token but I can't use policies that requires role authorization, because it does not initializes role manager service.

This version:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer();
builder.Services
        .AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender<IdentityUser>, MyEmailSender<IdentityUser>>();
```

allows me to interact with my app using just cookies. If try to use bearer token throws this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Identity.Bearer'. The registered sign-in schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddCookie("Identity.Bearer",...)?
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignInAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable`1 additionalClaims)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(TUser user, Boolean isPersistent, String loginProvider, Boolean bypassTwoFactor)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IdentityApiEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.<>c__1`1.<b__1_1>d.MoveNext()

What I need is a version that allows me handle role manager and can authenticate using both cookies and bearer token. I just need ASP.NET Core tokens, no third-party authorization tokens.

NOTE: This is my auth configuration adjusting it with documentation but this way I can login with token but Can't access the rolemanager's service !!!

```
    #region Config authorization   
    // Add services to the container.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            (options) => options
                    .UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Communities")));
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
    builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender<IdentityUser>, CommunitiesEmailSender<IdentityUser>>();
    builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
        .AddPolicy(Policy.Admin, policy => policy
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireRole(Roles.Admin));
    #endregion


    var app = builder.Build();

    #region enhance auth
    app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    #endregion
```

But with this config and this action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Policy = Policy.Admin)]
    [Route(nameof(SetUserRole))]
    public async Task SetUserRole(string userName, string desiredRole)
    {
        await CheckRoles();
        await AddRole(userName, desiredRole);
    }
```

Always receive 403 Forbidden, Policy is set ok, just use constants to avoid typos.
Aditionally I need access rolemanager at least in one controller

Comment: May I know when this exception has been thrown? While accessing the token or while using? In addition, I haven't seen any role configuration within your shared code. Would you kindly [`have a look at this official document`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for configuration?

Comment: Accoridng to the code snippet which attempts to use SignInManager with the scheme `"Identity.Bearer"`, which is not a registered sign-in scheme for cookies. This causes the error you encountered. Because using the same authentication scheme name ("Bearer") for both cookie and JWT authentication might lead to conflicts. It's recommended to use distinct scheme names.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Tks for answer , please see edits.

Comment: What does the (console) logging say before the 403 occurs? Most of the time these log messages are very helpful.

Comment: Furthermore: Use ` IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;` to get some more detailed logging about why the API returns a 403. (dont use in production, it exposes potential personal information about an user)

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen No additional output just  
Error: response status is 403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0), seems like protecting SPA'S is not allowed using roles.

```
"Using roles to add claims to a user can confuse the boundary 
between the user and their individual claims. This confusion is 
why the SPA templates are not designed around roles. In 
addition, for organizations migrating from an on-premises 
legacy system the proliferation of roles over the years can 
mean a role claim may be too large to be contained within a 
token usable by SPAs."
```

Due I'm working with an SPA type app, going to use simple claims aproach.